What would you use to update a template pdf and change out variable names in Nest.js
I am currently trying to build an API, that takes in a Post request containing a User object and a PDF acting as a template. After going over all the places within the PDF containing a variable like [NAME] and swapping it out with the provided user info, I will return the PDF.
I've made the endpoints in Nest.JS, so I was wondering whether you guys have used any libraries or packages that allow you to do something like that.
